# OrderBy не сортирует

Tags: c#

Есть следующий код

```
class TestSlot
{
    public double? Price;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var slots = new List<TestSlot>();
    var slot = new TestSlot();
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        slot = new TestSlot();
        slot.Price = 5 - i;
        slots.Append(slot);
    }
    /*
    slot = new TestSlot();
    slot.Price = null;
    slots.Append(slot);
    */
    var k = slots.OrderBy(x => x.Price).ToList();
    foreach (var z in k)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(z);
    }
}
```

Почему k.Count() == 0?

Так как я не могу запустить данный код, то не могу ответить на вопрос, который я задал себе изначально? Что будет, если пихнуть в slots объект с Price == null? (в коде эта часть закоменчена)

Comment: *Почему k.Count() == 0?* — с чего вы взяли?

Comment: *Что будет, если пихнуть в slots объект с Price == null?* — а какой тип имеет Price? `null` будут в самом начале скорее всего

Comment: Как это с чего. Проверил. Могу скрин приложить

Comment: @АндрейNOP пофиксил

Comment: А что такое `Append`? Я не помню у `List<>` такого метода

Comment: Ах, я понял вашу ошибку

Comment: @АндрейNOP Да, вы правы. Всё заработало. Спасибо

Comment: Дополнил про сортировку

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У коллекции `List<>` нет метода `Append()`: [документация](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Если вы нажмете <kbd>F12</kbd> на этом методе в студии, то увидите, что вы на самом деле вызываете метод `Enumerable.Append` из Linq (доступно с 4.7.1): [документация](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.append?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Этот метод (как и любые методы Linq) не изменяет входную коллекцию — он возвращает новую последовательность, которую вы потом просто никуда не сохраняете.

Для добавления элемента в `List` воспользуйтесь его методом `Add`.

PS: Можно, конечно, написать `slots = slots.Append(slot).ToList();`, но это неэффективно — список будет пересоздаваться каждый раз заново.

---

Что касается второй части вопроса: т. к. при вызове `OrderBy` вы не передаете экземпляр `IComparer<T>`, то для сравнения [будет использоваться `Comparer<T>.Default`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,2579), который, в свою очередь, для `Nullable<>`-типов [создает специальный `NullableComparer<T>`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/comparer.cs,67). Если посмотреть [реализацию `NullableComparer<T>.Compare()`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/comparer.cs,111), то вы увидите, что значения `null` в нем считаются меньшими любого не-`null`, поэтому при сортировке они будут помещены в самое начало списка.